# How to authenticate users in back end API when they are logged into Facebook?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, facebook-javascript-sdk, access-token

We're building a web application that consists of a separate front and back end:

- The front end is built in React. A user can log in to this front end     using his Facebook credentials (using the Facebook Login SDK). After     the user logs in, the front end receives the facebook_id, user_name      and an access token. The user can then do inputs that can be stored      in and received from the database.
- The front end communicates with      the back end through AJAX calls
  to different routes in the back end.
- The back end is built in Laravel as a REST API. When an AJAX request 
  is received, the right function is called to modify the    database
  with    the request's parameters.

What is the best way to make sure that the user that logs in to Facebook is the only one that can make request on behalf of that user_id? I was thinking about adding a 'token' column to the users table in the database, then generating a random token on login and sending this to the user. But that way the user could send a fake Facebook id to the server, generating an illegal token.

Laravel already has an authentication implementation called [Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/passport), but I'm not sure how to use this when the user is already logged in to Facebook. Maybe there is a more direct way of using the Facebook authentication in my back end, but I'm afraid that sending around the Facebook access tokens will compromise security. I have no experience with online securtiy, but I want my users to be safe.

I think the main problem lies in ensuring that every user that is logged in through Facebook will receive one user account on the back end. But it should not be possible to receive a user account if someone is not logged in. So I think the server should check in some way if the user is really logged in to Facebook and only then give out a user account and token.